# Biopython SeqIO to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, biopython, fasta

I have a FASTA file that can easily be parsed by [`SeqIO.parse`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).

I am interested in extracting sequence ID's and sequence lengths. I used these lines to do it, but I feel it's waaaay too heavy (two iterations, conversions, etc.)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd


# parse sequence fasta file
identifiers = [seq_record.id for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("sequence.fasta",
                                                           "fasta")]
lengths = [len(seq_record.seq) for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("sequence.fasta",
                                                             "fasta")]
#converting lists to pandas Series    
s1 = Series(identifiers, name='ID')
s2 = Series(lengths, name='length')
#Gathering Series into a pandas DataFrame and rename index as ID column
Qfasta = DataFrame(dict(ID=s1, length=s2)).set_index(['ID'])
```

I could do it with only one iteration, but I get a dict :

```
records = SeqIO.parse(fastaFile, 'fasta')
```

and I somehow can't get `DataFrame.from_dict` to work...

My goal is to iterate the FASTA file, and get ids and sequences lengths into a `DataFrame` through each iteration.

Here is a [short FASTA file](http://prodata.swmed.edu/pcma/info/fasta_format_file_example.htm) for those who want to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're spot on - you definitely shouldn't be parsing the file *twice*, and storing the data in a dictionary is a waste of computing resources when you'll just be converting it to `numpy` arrays later.

`SeqIO.parse()` returns a generator, so you can iterate record-by-record, building a list like so:

```
with open('sequences.fasta') as fasta_file:  # Will close handle cleanly
    identifiers = []
    lengths = []
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta'):  # (generator)
        identifiers.append(seq_record.id)
        lengths.append(len(seq_record.seq))
```

*See [Peter Cock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452991/815632) for a more efficient way of parsing just ID's and sequences from a FASTA file.*

The rest of your code looks pretty good to me. However, if you really want to optimize for use with `pandas`, you can read below:

---

### On minimizing memory usage

Consulting the [source of `panda.Series`](http://code.google.com/p/pandas/source/browse/trunk/pandas/core/series.py#80), we can see that `data` is stored interally as a `numpy` `ndarray`:

```
class Series(np.ndarray, Picklable, Groupable):
    """Generic indexed series (time series or otherwise) object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data:  array-like
        Underlying values of Series, preferably as numpy ndarray
```

If you make `identifiers` an `ndarray`, it can be used directly in `Series` without constructing a new array (the parameter `copy`, default `False`) will prevent a new `ndarray` being created if not needed. By storing your sequences in a list, you'll force Series to coerce said list to an `ndarray`.

#### Avoid initializing lists

If you know in advance exactly how many sequences you have (and how long the longest ID will be), you could initialize an empty `ndarray` to hold identifiers like so:

```
num_seqs = 50
max_id_len = 60
numpy.empty((num_seqs, 1), dtype='S{:d}'.format(max_id_len))
```

Of course, it's pretty hard to know exactly how many sequences you'll have, or what the largest ID is, so it's easiest to just let `numpy` convert from an existing list. However, this is *technically* the fastest way to store your data for use in `pandas`.

Comment: Thanks David, it did the trick. Thanks also for the "memory" comment!

Answer (score 6):

David has given you a nice answer on the `pandas` side, on the Biopython side you don't need to use `SeqRecord` objects via `Bio.SeqIO` if all you want is the record identifiers and their sequence length - this should be faster:

```
from Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO import SimpleFastaParser
with open('sequences.fasta') as fasta_file:  # Will close handle cleanly
    identifiers = []
    lengths = []
    for title, sequence in SimpleFastaParser(fasta_file):
        identifiers.append(title.split(None, 1)[0])  # First word is ID
        lengths.append(len(sequence))
```