# how to convert fasta file into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fasta

I have fasta file which contains around 900k protein sequences -  below is the first 3 for example:

```
>NP_000011.2 serine/threonine-protein kinase receptor R3 precursor [Homo sapiens]
MTLGSPRKGLLMLLMALVTQGDPVKPSRGPLVTCTCESPHCKGPTCRGAWCTVVLVREEGRHPQEHRGCGNLHRELCRGR
PTEFVNHYCCDSHLCNHNVSLVLEATQPPSEQPGTDGQLALILGPVLALLALVALGVLGLWHVRRRQEKQRGLHSELGES
>NP_000012.1 presenilin-1 isoform I-467 [Homo sapiens]
MTELPAPLSYFQNAQMSEDNHLSNTVRSQNDNRERQEHNDRRSLGHPEPLSNGRPQGNSRQVVEQDEEEDEELTLKYGAK
HVIMLFVPVTLCMVVVVATIKSVSFYTRKDGQLIYTPFTEDTETVGQRALHSILNAAIMISVIVVMTILLVVLYKYRCYK
>NP_000013.2 adenosine deaminase isoform 1 [Homo sapiens]
MAQTPAFDKPKVELHVHLDGSIKPETILYYGRRRGIALPANTAEGLLNVIGMDKPLTLPDFLAKFDYYMPAIAGCREAIK
RIAYEFVEMKAKEGVVYVEVRYSPHLLANSKVEPIPWNQAEGDLTPDEVVALVGQGLQEGERDFGVKARSILCCMRHQPN
```

I want to have them into a dataframe with the proper columns names looking like this:

```
ID              name                             sapiens        sequence  
>NP_000011.2    serine/threonine-protein kinase  [Homo sapiens] MTLGSPRKGLLMLLMALVTQGDPVKPSRGPLVTCTCESPHCKGPTCRGAWCTVVLVREEGRHPQEHRGCGNLHRELCRGRPTEFVNHY CDSHLCNHNVSLVLEATQPPSEQPGTDGQLALILGPVLALLALVALGVLGLWHVRRRQEKQRGLHSELGES
>NP_000012.1    presenilin-1 isoform I-467       [Homo sapiens] MTELPAPLSYFQNAQMSEDNHLSNTVRSQNDNRERQEHNDRRSLGHPEPLSNGRPQGNSRQVVEQDEEEDEELTLKYGAKHVIMLFVPVTLCMVVVVATIKSVSFYTRKDGQLIYTPFTEDTETVGQRALHSILNAAIMISVIVVMTILLVVLYKYRCYK
>NP_000013.2    adenosine deaminase isoform 1    [Homo sapiens] MAQTPAFDKPKVELHVHLDGSIKPETILYYGRRRGIALPANTAEGLLNVIGMDKPLTLPDFLAKFDYYMPAIAGCREAIKRIAYEFVEMKAKEGVVYVEVRYSPHLLANSKVEPIPWNQAEGDLTPDEVVALVGQGLQEGERDFGVKARSILCCMRHQPN
```

none of the below methods worked

```
df = open('sample.faa','r')
lines = df.readlines()
df.close()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
      lines[index] = line.strip()
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=('ID', 'name'))
i = 0
ID = "" 
name = ""  
for line in lines:
    if 'X' in line:
        ID = line.replace('X', "")
    else:
        name = re.sub(r']', "", line)
        df_result.loc[i] = [ID, name]
        i =i+1
```

```
f = open('sample.faa', encoding='utf8')
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
df
```

```
data = pd.read_csv('sample.faa', sep=',')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436789/biopython-seqio-to-pandas-dataframe has a recipe for converting a FASTA file to dataframes with BioPython but you'd have to extend that to split the title into id, name, and species (which is not hard at all per se).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you were able to read the file as a text, so now you have a list like:

```py
lines = [
    ">NP_000011.2 serine/threonine-protein kinase receptor R3 precursor [Homo sapiens] MTLGSPRKGLLMLLMALVTQGDPVKPSRGPLVTCTCESPHCKGPTCRGAWCTVVLVREEGRHPQEHRGCGNLHRELCRGRPTEFVNHYCCDSHLCNHNVSLVLEATQPPSEQPGTDGQLALILGPVLALLALVALGVLGLWHVRRRQEKQRGLHSELGES",
    ">NP_000012.1 presenilin-1 isoform I-467 [Homo sapiens] MTELPAPLSYFQNAQMSEDNHLSNTVRSQNDNRERQEHNDRRSLGHPEPLSNGRPQGNSRQVVEQDEEEDEELTLKYGAKHVIMLFVPVTLCMVVVVATIKSVSFYTRKDGQLIYTPFTEDTETVGQRALHSILNAAIMISVIVVMTILLVVLYKYRCYK",
    ">NP_000013.2 adenosine deaminase isoform 1 [Homo sapiens] MAQTPAFDKPKVELHVHLDGSIKPETILYYGRRRGIALPANTAEGLLNVIGMDKPLTLPDFLAKFDYYMPAIAGCREAIKRIAYEFVEMKAKEGVVYVEVRYSPHLLANSKVEPIPWNQAEGDLTPDEVVALVGQGLQEGERDFGVKARSILCCMRHQPN"
]
```

To convert it into the required dataframe, you can just iterate and do something like:

```py
frame = {k : [] for k in ["ID", "name", "sapiens", "sequence"]}

for line in lines:
    ID, *series, sequence = line.strip().split()
    
    # we want to process and find the name and sapiens
    # let's get the original series back, and process to find
    series = " ".join(series).split(" [")
    name = series[0]
    sapiens = "[" + series[1]
    
    for k, v in zip(["ID", "name", "sapiens", "sequence"], [ID, name, sapiens, sequence]):
        frame[k].append(v)
    
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

**Output Image**
[image]

Comment: this showed the following error:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was out of the station. I guess `ValueError` is raised at `sapiens = "[" + series[1]` if so, then there might be some different types of lines other than the ones you've provided. Please provide the data sample. I've also updated the answer with an o/p screenshot.